# Outlook find Email in inbox by string (part of body)

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I simply want to select all mail in my inbox that contain (in Body) a certain string. I thought Find would be a good Approach. Rather to make a for..each on all items in inbox...
However my command does (see below) not work. It brings "invalid condition"

Set Msg = Inbox.Items.Find("abc")

2 Questions:
1. How to fill in the desired condition?
2. What is result of that find? A single email or a collection I need to put in a variant or so

Answer (score 0):

The [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method locates and returns a Microsoft Outlook item object that satisfies the given Filter. See [Filtering Items Using Query Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869374.aspx) for more information about possible query strings. After the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx) method runs, the [FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862482.aspx) method finds and returns the next Outlook item in the specified collection. For example:

```
 Sub DemoFindNext() 
  Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
  Dim tdystart As Date 
  Dim tdyend As Date 
  Dim myAppointments As Outlook.Items 
  Dim currentAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem 

  Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
  tdystart = VBA.Format(Now, "Short Date") 
  tdyend = VBA.Format(Now + 1, "Short Date") 
  Set myAppointments = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items 
  Set currentAppointment = myAppointments.Find("[Start] >= """ & tdystart &    """ and [Start] <= """ & tdyend & """") 
  While TypeName(currentAppointment) <> "Nothing" 
   MsgBox currentAppointment.Subject 
   Set currentAppointment = myAppointments.FindNext 
  Wend 
 End Sub
```